# Check if docker has logged in via bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to check if user is logged in to docker registry by this simple script. If user is logged in, the output would be `Login Succeeded`, if not it will prompt for `Username`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(docker login registry.example.com | grep -E 'Login Succeeded') -z ] 
  then
    echo 'failed'
  else
    echo "ok"
fi
```

But this is failing as I always get the output of the `docker login` command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most command line tools, `docker login` returns an exit code `0` when it is successful and a non-zero exit code for failures. This is good enough to attempt the check directly in the `if` condition as below

```bsh
if docker login registry.example.com > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will assert the `if` condition to true when login is successful and suppress any warnings/errors thrown by re-directing both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

Or if you have stick with `grep`, you can use the `-q` flag to just suppress the usual match output but just set the exit code back to shell to use

```bsh
if docker login registry.example.com 2>/dev/null | grep -q "Login Succeeded"
```

---

Your `if` condition with `[ $(..) -z ]` can never be successful as the shell expects `-z` operator to provided with an operand value, but it doesn't see one and the result of command substitution `$(..)`, whatever be the value, will always throw a syntax error.